# google document translator (uploading local file) in my website

Tags: google-translate

is there any way to use google document translator application in my website? i did it like they do it, but i cannot access to their server. i got this message:

Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /translate_f from this server.

does someone know if it's possible to do this? if not, is there another tool that make it possible?

thanks in advance!!! :)

sOle

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) instead.  This is the officially sanctioned way doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GWT, there's a Java API - http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/LanguageGettingStarted as well, and that's worked really well for me.